# Is this equation: $y' = \sin(2\,x-y^2)$ solvable?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I claimed the equation is not solvable bc the integral curves are flowing into each other (meaning to me there are multiple solutions to the same starting conditions hence no distinct solutions). Furthermore I asserted the function are continuous. They should be.

Is anything wrong with the statement above? Wolfram isn't computing any further.

Comment: Existence and Uniqueness are not one and the same. The lack of one does not mean the lack of the other.

Comment: The differential equation $y' = y$ is solved by $y = Ce^x$; therefore, the differential equation has no unique solution.

Comment: What you're claiming in your first sentence seems to contradicts the Picard–Lindelöf theorem. Could you give an example of what you have in mind?

Comment: I just want to describe whether solutions exists or not. It seems like my claim 'unique solutions do not exist' is marked wrong. Thus are there no solutions at all?

Comment: for example $y' = \sqrt{|y|}$ doesn't seem to have unique solutions no matter what starting conditions bc of the flow. That's what I think